# Может ли отображаться видео в качестве фона?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть картинка в качестве фона и блок поверх.
Этим кодом на клавишу `~` я скрываю блок, остается только фоновое изображение:

```
addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 192)
        document.body.style.display = (document.body.style.display === 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';
})
```

Теперь на фон через тег video я поставил видео, но когда я нажимаю `~`, то скрывается блок вместе с фоновым видео и остается белый фон, а должен скрываться только блок. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: покажи пример с картинкой, который работает и с видео, который не работает

Comment: Вы скрываете полностью тело "body"  а видео наверное находится в самом body или при его скрытие размер(высота) страницы равна 0

Comment: @Grundy
Для картинки js-кода выше достаточно, если стоит background-image в css
https://pastebin.com/VNaw5WRs

Comment: @Даниил не подскажите тогда как изменить js код, чтобы скрывалось не всё тело (хотя для картинки это работает), а только для section например или куда мне поместить видео?

Comment: Дмитрий, что-бы получить внятный вопрос, надо как минимум  объяснить, что ты делаешь, чего хочешь добиться... ну есть кусок js кода, всем понятно, что он делает, а вот что именно ты хочешь и что у тя не получается не понятно вообще... тебе @Grundy, правильно сказал, выложи код, а не ссылку и опиши нормально что у тя не получается...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что то тип того?

```js
 
addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 192) 
        document.getElementById("videobg").style.display = (document.getElementById("videobg").style.display === 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';
      //  document.body.style.display = (document.body.style.display === 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';
})
```

```css
  body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #000; 
}
video { 
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
 background: url('//demosthenes.info/assets/images/polina.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  transition: 1s opacity;
}
  
 
  
body { 
  background: url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/0d/cb/46/0dcb4612451fd35a55a2a28a11ca2b50.jpg) #000 no-repeat fixed;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
  }
```

```html
<video id="videobg" poster="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/polina.jpg" id="bgvid" playsinline autoplay muted loop>  
  <source src="http://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/polina.webm" type="video/webm">
  <source src="http://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/polina.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Да, именно так у меня сейчас только поверх в section у меня текст ещё, а нужно чтобы вместо картинки после нажатия ~ продолжало играть это видео, а текст - скрылся

Comment: Ну не знаю, вроде то что нужно. Вы код не показали, задача выполнена. Можете переделать под себя данный код и отметить ответ решением.  Или же всетаки показать  ваш код. Мы тут не ваги)

Comment: По этому Даниил, на такие абстрактные вопросы не стоит отвечать, он тебя не спрашивает, как сделать, хочет, чтобы ты еще и допилил, а еще и возмущается, что что-то не то, не до пилено до его задумки)))))  Которая только в его голове..  Это секрет коммерческий, что-бы  ни кто идею не смог украсть...

Comment: @Даниил, я предельно просто объяснил,что у меня есть фоновое видео и текст поверх него, при скрытии должен скрываться текст, а видео проигрываться дальше, но вы предоставили код, который у меня  уже был и всё равно спасибо

Comment: @Дмитрий а мне показалось что я ответил на ваш вопрос "Скрывается блок вместе с фоновым видео и остается белый фон, а должен скрываться только блок".  Разве нет?   В вопросе вообще про текст ничего нет)))

Comment: Будьте добры писать хорошие вопросы с примерами, скринами, с кодом и четко сформулированным вопросом.  Чем лучше вопрос тем лучше ответ.

Comment: @Даниил понял, извините, большое спасибо, всё получилось